# IOS GMSGeocoder not accurate

Tags: ios, maps, gmsplace

I am developing an iOS app that is using google maps and google places.

I am using GMSGeocoder to reverse geocode coordinates because I need to get the sublocality and locality.

However, I sometimes receive sublocality as nil, but on my android version I am using Geocoder class and I am receiving a valid sublocality for the same coordinates , What could be the problem? Please help me

Comment: in few locations, apple maps frameworks are not much reliable, at some places they doesn't used to return sublocality.

Comment: I am not using apple’s , I am using google GMSGeocoder